# Transform not working for axvspan (or axhspan)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fighting to make matplotlib `axvspan` (or `axhspan`) to work with transformed coordinates, but I'm unable to.
Particularly, I'd like to define `ymin` and `ymax` to work in `transData` coordinates and not in `transAxes` coordinates (its default).
Here is my test code (my goal is to draw the red an blue background between the horizontal lines at `y=0` and `y=1`):

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim([-1, 2])
ax.set_xlim([0, 15])
ax.axhline(y=0)
ax.axhline(y=1)
# tried different ways to do this.
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transData)
ax.axvspan(8, 10, ymin=0, ymax=1, transform=trans, alpha=0.1, color='blue')
ax.axvspan(10, 12, ymin=0.1, ymax=0.8, transform=(ax.transData, ax.transData), alpha=0.5, color='red')
plt.show()
```

The output is the following:

[image]

Note:I know how to make this using e.g. `patches.rectangle`, but I would like to make this work (or understand why it doesn't) with `axvspan`

Comment: According to the source code,  `get_xaxis_transform()` is always used, ignoring the `transform=` parameter. So, the answer to "why doesn't it work", is "the source code doesn't use it".  A guess "why is the source like that?" might be that the function only exists as an extension to drawing a rectangle. Apart from creating a rectangle, there is also `ax.fill(...)` or `ax.fill_between([8, 10], 0, 1)`

Comment: These functions are designed to work like this: the idea is to mark an interval of the data. You should not use them for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: use a diy transform]

I have tested this method also with a reversed *y*-axis, and it works in both cases

```
def limits(a, b, ax):
    if a>b : a, b = b, a
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    dy = ymax-ymin
    return ((y-ymin)/dy for y in (a, b))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim([-1, 2]) # or ax.set_ylim([2, -1])
ax.set_xlim([0, 15])
ax.axhline(y=0)
ax.axhline(y=1)
ax.axvspan(8, 10, *limits(0, 1, ax))
plt.show()
```